# How to atomically update a map key in Aerospike?

Tags: aerospike

```
@AerospikeEntity(nameSpace = Constants.NAMESPACE, setName = Constants.ABC_SET)

public class ABCModel implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @AerospikeKey
    private String cycle;
    private long  debitAmount;
    private long  creditAmount;
   private Map<String, AtomicDouble> map;
}
```

suppose atomically i want to update some key inside this given map ,how can i achieve this in Aerospike java client ?

Answer (score 3):

Please see code examples here:  https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-java/blob/master/examples/src/com/aerospike/examples/OperateMap.java